# Java Class SimpleDate NOT SimpleDateFormat Issue In Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans-8

In Netbeans, I'm running into an error when I try to instantiate and use SimpleDate NOT SimpleDateFormat.

Here is the error message:

> error: cannot find symbol SimpleDate currentDay = new SimpleDate(1,
>   21, 2016);

Everywhere I look, I keep running into answers for SimpleDateFormat and not SimpleDate.

Comment: What is the SimpleDate class ?

Comment: I don't believe Java has a native `SimpleDate` class. Is it a class that you are creating?

Comment: Its actually used as example in the book "Java Illuminated" and when I try to run it, I get the error on complile.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry but Java doesn't have a `SimpleDate` class.

The standard [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) class has a constructor `Date(int year, int month, int date)` but it has been deprecated for a long time.

[image: Java SE 7 Documentation]

Comment: Hi thanks for the info. This is actually an example in the java book that I'm using for a course but its throwing an error when it compiles.